# Set source of wpf image

Tags: wpf, image

I have a wpf app with an image in the xaml:

```
<Image HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="131" Margin="550,0,1306,-960" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="58" Source="../images/blue.JPG" Name="im_Izq"/>
```

And I want to change the source image from the code behind.
I tried the following:

```
im_Izq.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("../../images/red.JPG"));
```

but, when running it, I get this error:

System.UriFormatException: 'URI no válido: no se puede determinar el formato del URI.'

Can you help me? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the image file is located in a project folder named `images`, and set the Build Action of the file to `Resource`.

```
im_Izq.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/images/red.JPG"));
```

or use

```
im_Izq.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/projectname;component/Images/up.ico", UriKind.Relative));
```

Comment: I have it like this and it doesn't work.
My doubt:
pack://application:,,, goes like this or do I have to put the name of the application?

Comment: Take a look at the answers to the questions marked as duplicate.

Comment: I added another code snippet to the answer, you can test it too